# Can i store multiple images in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Can I store multiple images in one field in MySQL database? I'm a beginner in php development and i don't have any idea how to store multiple images in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You'll store the link (in the database) of the image that you uploaded. With this said, you can store many links to different images. When you need an image, you'll just need to pick the link from the database with a select request and then use it in a `<img />` tag to display your image (don't forget to test if your image is available before).